# Windows Update stuck at 0KB 0% even after clean bo

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-update

my Windows Update progress is stuck at 0KB and 0%. I have tried everything I have found on the internet to fix it. I've tried stopping `wuauserv` `bits` and `cryptsvc`, deleting my SoftwareDistribution folder and restarting them. I've tried the DISM tool (which just hangs after displaying the image version) and I've tried doing it on a clean boot. Nothing works! Is there any way I can get these updates (because I would like to upgrade to Windows 10) that doesn't involve reinstalling Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many sites seem to describe a similar problem, the fix is

1. In Explorer navigate to `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download`
2. Delete **everything** you see in there.
3. Open an **administrator** command prompt.
4. enter the command `wuauclt.exe /updatenow`

Windows update should now show that it is downloading Windows 10.